# Hide variable product dropdown that has a unique variation selected by default in Woocommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a unique issue. I am using a plugin where they are not able to support the request.  I need to split out variations into separate items, but if I copy and paste and turn them into a simple product, then I can't sync the count for the product to track inventory stock. As a workaround I needed to be able to disable the variations I do not need, keeping only the one that I do need.  But here is where I am having trouble.  If I have one variation enabled, then I do not want to show the dropdown, and instead want it to look like a simple product on the UI.  I tried everything and cannot get it to work.

I even tried using

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hide_invisible_variations', '__return_true', 10, 3 );
```

with no success as they are visible and not hidden even though the counts are 0, the price is 0, and the item is disabled.

How can I show the product page with no drop-down?  Take it one step further; I delete all variations except the one that I need to keep.  I need to keep it in variations mode due to the plugin that syncs. How do I display it without any dropdowns showing?

Example logic:

If product type is a variation and enabled count == 1 then special ui display, else normal.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT:** The code **only works** when the unique variation is selected as **default** form value:
>
> [image]

The following code will hide from variable products that have only one variation enabled **and selected by default**, the attribute dropdown and the selected variation price:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'single_unique_variation_ui', 10 );
function single_unique_variation_ui(){
    global $product;

    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') )
        return; // Only variable products

    $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations(); // Get available variations
    $default_attributes   = $product->get_default_attributes();   // Get default attributes

    // Only for a unique selected variation by default
    if( ! ( sizeof($available_variations) == 1 && sizeof($default_attributes) == 1 ) )
        return;

    // Get the unique variation
    $variation = reset($available_variations);

    // Loop through
    if( reset($variation['attributes']) == reset($default_attributes) ) :
    // Styles
    ?>
    <style>
        div.woocommerce-variation-price, table.variations { display:none; }
    </style>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Without the code** *(the normal woocommerce behavior)*:

[image]

**With the code** *(that hide the attribute dropdown and the price)*:

[image]

> It will give you the same UI than simple products

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!  I greatly appreciate it.  It works perfectly!

Comment: I have a similar problem and would therefore like to join this question:

I have a product variation, based on the color of a product: red or green. Now the red product should have the attribute "machine wash 30 degrees" and the green product "machine wash 40 degrees". So I have selected both attributes for "Use for Variation". I also see the selection for the color.

Unfortunately, a selection for the attribute "Machine Wash" is also displayed. But this should not be selectable at all, it should be assigned to a fixed attribute. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: This is how i tried (Screenshot: https://ibb.co/hdhBf1h ). But in the frontend there is a Select Field for the Machinewash attribute... This Select Field is correctly set up: It just allows you to choose 30° if you chose the red shirt, and to choose 40° if you chose the green shirt. But the Machine Wash Attribute should just be an information - not a selectable attribute.

Comment: Is there another way to add seperate attributes for each product variant?

Comment: @MartinP. You should need to add some jQuery code for the related variable product to make it work as you would like.