# Hide dropdown with only 1 variable in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce, and I'm looking for a way to automatically hide the dropdown feature when there is only 1 option for that specific variable/variation.

I Tried [Hide variable product dropdown that has a unique variation selected by default in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564972/hide-variable-product-dropdown-that-has-a-unique-variation-selected-by-default-i/52565307#52565307)

It hides the dropdown feature when only 1 variation is available for that product.

This code seemed to have worked for another guy, but I cannot seem to make it work in my case.

I tried to experiment with the code, but I couldn't seem to make it work.

Any help will definitely be appreciated

**Edit:** 
Currently, what I have are 2 attributes. 1 of them has only 1 variation/option, and the other 1 has 3 variation/option. What do I need to change to the code to make it work for my case?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I cannot seem to make it work now"? Does it show something on your browser for products with only one option? If yes, what is it? For products with more than one variation, do you have your page displayed as expected? Do you have a blank screen?

Comment: You may have only one variation that does not have the default attribute as attribute, but another.
(I may update the answer once you provide some more information)

Comment: Sorry but **this code still perfectly works**… But it **requires that unique variation to be selected as default variation** (displayed "selected" by default). If not the code doesn't work. This is specified at the beginning of the answer… So please read before saying that it don't work. Additionally if you dont make changes to a stackOverFlow answer code, Just add the link in your question.

Comment: Hey guys, sorry about that... This is my first time asking a question, but I am very thankful for the help. I did have a look through at the edited thread by @LoicTheAztec, and it did work but only when there is **one** attribute. Currently, what I have are 2 attributes. 1 of them has only 1 variation/option, and the other 1 has 3 variation/option. I would like to hide the attribute that only has one variation/option, while still showing the 1 attribute that has 3 variation/option.

Just want to say sorry again for being confusing/misleading! Thanks again!

Comment: @websiteguy As the thread title says "1 active default selected variation" … You will need to make your own code based on your specific requirements and variation settings. Anyway a preselected variation is needed and you will need to hide the little "clear" button too (that reset all dropdowns).

Comment: Thank you for getting back so quickly @LoicTheAztec, and I apologize if I am not phrasing my questions correctly. What I was hoping to do is to just hide the dropdown whenever that variable only has 1 option (active or non active), while still showing the dropdowns for other variables that have more than 1 option. In my case, as the products get uploaded to Woocommerce automatically (via CSV as a lot of products get uploaded in one go), I do not get to make the variable "active" for every product as there are too many. Please do let me know if I should create a new thread for this, thanks.