# Woocommerce hide variation dropdown with only 1 option

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have some products with a specific attribute which most of the times has a single option.

If that is the case, i'd like to hide the option picker (drop-down) on my product page.

The attribute is called `package size` and it is set to `one` **by default** for all products. But it is confusing for the customer too see the option picker if there is only one option available.

I'd like to remove it for products with only one package size option.

Any ideas ?

Greetings

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a search engine, it helps you to find a answer on the attempt you made to solve the question. If you don't show the attempted code from you then the question will be closed without answers.

Comment: Please, provide some code in order to help you

Comment: I have no code, thats why iam asking. Some code that hide the options to select a certain attribute if the variation only has one option available.

Comment: Basicly i want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52564972/hide-variable-product-dropdown-that-has-a-unique-variation-selected-by-default-i but for products with more than one variation option. So a customer can still choose the color but since the size of the cloth is always small it hides the dropdown